# Count SQLite Android how to display cursor properly

Tags: android, sqlite, time, count

I have a simple function with SQLite raw query, it looks like :

```
public Cursor getOccurations ()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data= db.rawQuery("select count(*) from Beacon_occurations where BEACON_ADDRESS='" + COL_2 + "' and TIME='" + COL_3 +"'", null);
    return data;
}
```

And now here is a question, how should I display it properly ? When I try do something like :

```
            data = db.getOccurations();
            string = data.toString();
            Log.e("Message",string);
```

I get : **Message: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@1a81ae97** ofc it isn't data which I want get :)
How should I do it properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such debug logging purposes, have a look at [`DatabaseUtils#dumpCursorToString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#dumpCursorToString(android.database.Cursor)).

For non-debug purposes, call `getString()` et al. on the cursor.

Comment: getString() requires column index and I don't have it

Comment: Ok i use this DatabaseUtils#dumpCursorToString() and it works :)

Comment: For `getString()` note that your cursor has exactly one column and one row.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
while(data.moveToNext()){
String s = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex("column Name"));
}
```

or

```
while(data.moveToNext()){
    String s = data.getString(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading a single value from a query is easier with a helper function, such as [longForQuery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) or [stringForQuery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#stringForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])):

```java
public long getOccurations()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    return DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db,
            "select count(*) from Beacon_occurations where BEACON_ADDRESS=? and TIME=?",
            new String[]{ COL_2, COL_3 });
}
```

But to count rows, there is an even easier helper function, [queryNumEntries()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])):

```java
public long getOccurations()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(
            db, "Beacon_occurations",
            "BEACON_ADDRESS=? and TIME=?",
            new String[]{ COL_2, COL_3 });
}
```